# bubble sort on Multi-dimensional Arrays

Tags: c, arrays

Today i tried to sort a Multi-dimensional Arrays and i just can't figure out, why it doesn't work.

The algorithm does the swap of first letter, but doesn't swap the whole string. Here is a working [DEMO](http://ideone.com/3rUjYH) which shows that the algorithm prints alphabetically Initials of every string found.

The same algorithm used to swap the whole string not just the first letter, doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char arr[][10] = {"Michael" , "Tanja" ,"Adda", "Jenny", "Kimberly", "Walter" , "Donna"};
    size_t length = sizeof arr / sizeof *(arr + 0);
    unsigned int i,j, k=0;
    char *tmp;


    for (i = 0 ; i < length-1; i++){
        for (k = 0 ; k < length-i-1; k++){
            if (arr[k][0] > arr[k+1][0]){
                tmp = arr[k];
                strcpy(arr[k], arr[k+1]);
                strcpy(arr[k+1], tmp);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted Array:\n");
    for ( j = 0 ; j < length ; j++ ){
        printf("%s  ", arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output which i get is:

```
Adda  Adda  Adda  Donna  Donna  Donna  Donna
```

and it should be:

```
Adda Donna Jenny Kimberly Michael Tanja Walter
```

Comment: The problem is that `tmp = arr[k];` stores the address of `arr[k]` in `tmp`. Remember: Memory addresses are constant and do not change. Also, You can use `sizeof *arr` instead of `sizeof *(arr + 0)`

Comment: @CoolGuy Iknow that, i guess i just ignored that part. Thank you and wish you Happy new year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tmp` is just a pointer. So during the assignment `tmp = arr[k];` and subsequent `strcpy()`, it's lost due to `arr[k]` being overwritten with `arr[k+1]`.  But you need to *copy* the string during swap. So use a buffer:

```
char tmp[256];
```

and

```
  strcpy(tmp , arr[k]);
  strcpy(arr[k], arr[k+1]);
  strcpy(arr[k+1], tmp);
```

Comment: I suggest using `char tmp[10];` instead of `char tmp[256];`

Comment: @CoolGuy `256` has been picked as the best choice after a number of dice rolls :D Both are arbitrary sizes anyway and 10 might be too close to comfort considering we are dealing with *names*. The "right size" can only be decided by OP depending on the input data OP handles with.

Comment: Sorry for the late Answer. Thank you and Happy new year.

Comment: @Michi Happy new year to you too :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 tmp = arr[k];
```

Due to `tmp` pointing to `arr[k]` ,after copying `arr[k+1]` in `arr[k]` and copying `tmp` in latter , you get same value , as `arr[k]` is itself modified (`tmp` *points to this modified value*).

You can do this instead -

```
char tmp[20];
strcpy(tmp,arr[k]);
```

Comment: I suggest using `char tmp[10];` instead of `char tmp[20];`

Comment: @CoolGuy To prevent overflow while copying to other array ?

Comment: 10 because `arr` has 10 slots in each row: `char arr[][10]`. `char tmp[20]` wastes 10 bytes.

Comment: @CoolGuy Ok, but OP should consider to give desired size .

Comment: Or you could be happy with the working example he provided, and optimize when you believe its necessary (and how you learn to optimize it) :)